# Adding a vertical linebar to a ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to add a vertical scalebar to basic manual plots. My script is written in this format:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = df$xx) +
geom_point(aes(y = df$yy))
```

where `df` is a dataframe that looks like this:

```
   xx         yy          zz       xz
1 -10      0.0000000   0.000000   0.0000000
2  -9      0.8995455   1.371060   0.7044286
```

I've tried the `scalebar` function in `raster` to no avail. Every solution I have found deals with maps, which is not the case here. Am I missing something very obvious? Thank you.

An example of the plot

[image]

The red line was (crudely) added in Paint to show what I need, just a standard black line is sufficient.

Comment: What are you wanting the scalebar to show - do you want to map another variable to for example, colour(unrelated dont use df$xx / df$yy in ggplot, just use xx or yy)

Comment: eg `ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt, colour=disp)) + geom_point()`

Comment: I need it to show vertical height, specifically I need a line of distance 60 (along the y-axis). Thanks for the tip as well, complete novice here!

Comment: Its not completely clear (at least to me) what you want. Could you try to make an example - add a few more rows of your data, and then show the plot. Using that small example indicate what the scalebar should show (also try and keep the variable names consistent ie is vertical height  == yy). Thanks

Comment: This doesn't solve your problem, but don't use `$` inside `aes`, use bare variable names instead. Perhaps you can simply draw one yourself inside the plot area with `geom_segment` or `annotate(geom = "segment", ...)`.

Comment: @Emma is this roughly what you want? `ggplot(df, aes(x = xx, y = yy)) + geom_point() + geom_line(aes(x=c(-10.2, -10.2), y=c(0,60)))`

Comment: @Miff that works on its own but when added to the script gives the following error: "Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (9): x, y."

Comment: @user20650 I've updated the question with an image link. I need to add a black line roughly where the red one is!

Comment: @Emma ; `ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) + geom_point() +
  geom_errorbar(aes(x=15, ymin=3, ymax=4), col="red")`

Comment: @user20650 Great idea, this works nicely and is easy to customise. Cheers!

Comment: @user20650 This will plot the errorbar once for each point, you might not notice it on some output devices, on others it looks strange. For such use-cases it is much better to use annotate().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ggplot you can use annotate() to add elements to your plot. The scalebar you want looks like an errorbar, so I used that. Also I changed your code slightly, so you don't need to provide aes mappings in geom_point().

```
library("ggplot2")

df = data.frame(xx=c(1,2,3,4,5), yy=c(2,1,6,7,8))

ggplot(df, aes(x = xx, y = yy)) +
  geom_point() +
  annotate("errorbar", x=0, ymin=4, ymax=7, color="red")
```